Why is mass flux treated as independent components while interactions between directions are considered in momentum flux?
As a beginner in fluid mechanics, when I encountered the principle of mass conservation and the momentum equation in order to derive the Navier-Stokes equations, I noticed a fundamental difference in how mass flux and momentum flux are treated across control volume surfaces.
In the case of applying the principle of mass conservation to derive the continuity equation, mass flux across the control volume boundaries is decomposed into independent components according to the $x$,$y$, and  $z$ directions. For example, when focusing on the two surfaces perpendicular to the  $x$ -direction, the mass flux depends only on the velocity component $u$ in this direction, with no influence from the other velocity components $v$ and $w$ , as shown in the attached images:

However, when transitioning to the momentum equation and applying it to the same control volume, it becomes apparent that the momentum flux in any given direction is influenced by velocity components in all other directions. For instance, if we again look at the two surfaces perpendicular to the $x$-direction, we find that the momentum flux in this direction depends not only on the velocity $u$  but also on the velocity components $v$ and $w$  in the $y$- and $z$ -directions, as shown in the attached images:

Here, I am confused because I do not understand the physical or real reason that led to this distinction in how the two fluxes are treated. I kindly ask for clarification on this matter. As for the images and approach I used above, they can be found in any standard textbook on fluid mechanics.

The basic reason is simply that momentum is a vector quantity while mass is a scalar quantity. When momentum flows across a surface, it is the quantity itself, a vector, which transfers. Not just a component of the momentum.
You can have momentum normal to a plane transfer, but you can also have momentum tangential to a plane transfer. This is regardless of whether the transfer is convective or through some force or field.

Why, for example, didn’t we make the flux density of mass affect the control surface with its three components, as happens with the flux density of momentum, or vice versa?

In order to have a flux affect a control surface with three components you need two vectors: one to define the control surface normal direction and the other to describe the three components of the flux through the surface. With a mass flux across a control surface you only have one vector from the control surface itself. With a momentum flux across a control surface you have two, one from the control surface and the other from the momentum.

I agree with you that mass is a scalar quantity and momentum is a vector quantity. However, when we deal with surfaces, we do not deal with mass itself but with its flux, which is a vector quantity. So, what prevents it from having tangential and normal flux components on the surface, just like momentum flux?

A scalar flux is a vector. A vector flux is a tensor. In order to have normal and tangential flux components you need a tensor.

This distinction you mentioned arises from our consideration that the flux density of momentum, with its three components, applies over the control volume, while the flux density of mass applies only with one component on the control surface, specifically the component perpendicular to it. My exact question is: why did we differentiate between these two considerations? Why, for example, didn’t we make the flux density of mass affect the control surface with its three components, as happens with the flux density of momentum, or vice versa?

@BezinaTaki I added another paragraph. I hope that helps

Thank you very much for your help.
